# Does RedHat OpenJdk 64 bits exists?

Tags: 64-bit, redhat, java

All is in the title and I can't find clear information on the web.

Many thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is the output from my RHEL 6 server:

```
[root@red6 ~]# yum list '*openjdk*'
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Installed Packages
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64            1:1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.8.el6_1   @rhel-x86_64-server-6
Available Packages
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64      1:1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.8.el6_1   rhel-x86_64-server-6 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64    1:1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.8.el6_1   rhel-x86_64-server-6
```

It seems that OpenJDK exist and is available in standard RHEL distribution.

You can install it by executing as a `root` user:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this page for instructions on how to download it. http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Comment: Thanks but I already checked this page and was not able to know if this will install a 64 bit version of the jre/jdk on 64 bits platform or not ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I can't try it myself because i am in a big company and I am not root on my workstation. Thus before asking to the IT to install it, I asked the question here on Stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: If you work in a big company, I would ask IT to install the 64-bit version of OpenJDK as this is your requirement.  You shouldn't need to tell them how to do their job. ;)

Comment: I agree ;-) But for now I don't have the answer to my question ;-)